# How to set focus to Fieldmanager in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I am new to blackberry. Can we set focus and click event to verticalFieldManager in BlackBerry?

Here is my code:

```
 VerticalFieldManager itemdesc=new VerticalFieldManager(Field.FOCUSABLE);


          LabelField pdtitem=new LabelField(pdts.getProducts_name(),LabelField.FOCUSABLE){
              protected void drawFocus(Graphics graphics, boolean on)    
             {          
                // setSpace(5, 5);      
                 super.drawFocus(graphics, on);  
                 }
              protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new desc(V,j));
                return true;
            }


          };



          itemdesc.add(pdtitem);

          Bitmap cartbt=Bitmap.getBitmapResource("cart3.png");
          BitmapField cartbtn=new BitmapField(cartbt,Field.FOCUSABLE){
              protected void drawFocus(Graphics graphics, boolean on)    
             {          
                 setSpace(5, 5);      
                 super.drawFocus(graphics, on);  
                 }

              protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  PopupScreen pp=new PopupScreen(new login());

                Dialog.alert("hai");
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(pp);
                return super.navigationClick(status, time);
            }
          };
```

Comment: Yes, you can set and click event to a Field Manager.

Comment: I think your main problem is you want to use inert user interface elements (LabelField and Bitmap) as active user interface elements. This will leave you with two issues: 1) your have to nearly re-write the elements to do what you want (as you are finding out); 2) the user will not have the visual clues to know what to do. I suggest using ButtonField objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add a method to to your new HorizontalFieldManager

```
public boolean isFocusable(){
return true;
```

}